# Swift How to follow CGPath not from begin

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I would be grateful for one more advice:
I've created a CGPath and I'd like a sprite to follow this path from a point where a sprite made a contact with a path.

How to follow the CGPath from a selected point?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mike. You should add some code to allow other people  to replicate your issue. Summarily, from what I've understand from your question, you can't: you must rebuild the path from the contact point but I could wrong because I don't know what kind of path you have (circle, irregular polygon..). Take a look to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Alessandro, thank you for your comments.
The code I guess is too long. The question is more like general.
I've created a UIBezierPath() as a irregular path. Then I get it as a CGPath
and then I run an action on my sprite SKAction.follow(CGPath:path)

It works ok, but starts every time from the beginning of path. I need to start from the point of a path where my sprite meets the path. It will be more often somewhere on the path, not on the beginning.